# PHP connect to Google Cloud Sql Instance database with mysqli_connect

Tags: php, google-cloud-sql

I'm new with using `Google Cloud SQL` and `PHP`. I'm not able to connect to my `Cloud SQL Instance` using `mysqli_connect`. I have been doing lots of research online but I'm still not able to connect. I have stated the variables in the `test.php` but I don't know how to use them. Please Help

I'm trying to make an `android app`, where I will have to show data from a database. I'm using method of having `php` files stored in the cloud storage and my app would send `GET` or `POST` request to the `php` files and the `php` files would return data from the database. So how can I use `php` only to connect to the database?

`test.php:`

```
<?php
    $public_ip_address = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; // Public IP address of the Instance of Google Cloud SQL
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $instance = "instance_1";
    $database = "db1";

    $conn = mysqli_connect("cloudipad:" + $public_ip_address, $user, $password, $database);
?>
```

`Someone help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :(`

Comment: Have you [followed the docs?](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql)

Comment: Yeah. Many times. But the steps are very very unclear

Comment: I have read it again and again and yet `mysqli_connect` is not even mentioned once. Or is it that we cannot connect to the instance using `mysqli_connect`

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_connect works fine for me, to connect a PHP app running on Google Cloud App Engine to Cloud SQL...

```
// DMBS here means database management system, like Cloud SQL
define('HOSTSPEC', NULL);
define('USERNAME', '[MY_DBMS_USERNAME]');
define('PASSWORD', '[MY_DBMS_PASSWORD]');
define('DATABASE_INSTANCE_NAME', NULL); // Or the name of a database instance within your Cloud SQL instance.
define('PORT', NULL);
define('SOCKET', '/cloudsql/[GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NAME]:[GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION]:[CLOUD_SQL_DBMS_INSTANCE_NAME]');

// Option 1. Object-oriented style...
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOSTSPEC, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_INSTANCE_NAME, PORT, SOCKET);

// Option 2. Procedural style...
$DBMSresource = mysqli_connect(HOSTSPEC, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_INSTANCE_NAME, PORT, SOCKET);
if (!$DBMSresource)
    // log and handle error, maybe exit...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sql implements DataModelInterface
{
    private $dsn;
    private $user;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password)
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

 private function newConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: invalid data source name in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexBox\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\flexBox\test.php(4): PDO->__construct('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexBox\test.php on line 4`

Comment: please follow google doc https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql

and 

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/tree/master/2-structured-data/src/DataModel

Comment: can you refer me to which section should I read. I have spend 4 hours reading that, everything written in it is too vague.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/tree/master/2-structured-data/src/DataModel

Comment: I can't find `mysqli_query` in any of those files

Comment: this example provide pdo connection if you execute query follow pdo method $pdo = $this->newConnection();

$pdo = $this->newConnection();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id');
        $statement->bindValue('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: I'm new to php, I cannot understand this advance syntax being used `->`

Comment: Before you read PDO connection in php. This is sample for query execute in pdo connection   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Is there any other online `Cloud SQL` which can be easily connected to `php` with one command like the `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191502/discussion-between-rajmobiapp-and-aman).

Comment: Sorry I'll have to leave in 20 minutes. But if you know any other online `Database Storages` which can be easily connected to `php mysqli_connect` let me know.

Comment: `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$public_ip_address.";dbname=".$database, $user, $password);` 

I tried this, but it fails

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), you're passing the first parameter wrongly.

And yes, you can use MySQLi to connect to a Cloud SQL instance. If it is locally, you should use the Cloud SQL Proxy following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql).

Once you have the Cloud SQL Proxy listening, and changed the last row of your code snippet to:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $user, $password, $database);
```

You should connect successfully.

Comment: So after downloading the `Cloud SQL Proxy` what do I do. Why is `127.0.0.1` being used?

Comment: I run the `Cloud SQL Proxy` but nothing happens

Comment: Is it compulsory to use this `Cloud SQL Proxy`?

Comment: I'm trying to make an android app, where I will have to show data from a database. I'm using method of having `php` files stored in the cloud storage and my app would send `GET` or `POST` request to the `php` files and the `php` files would return data from the database. So how can I use `php` only to connect to the database?

Comment: From where do you want to connect to the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: From a php file which will be stored in google cloud storage.

Comment: Please read the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) on hosting static websites with Google Cloud Storage, No server-side script can be executed in this context.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can connect by mysqli to Google Cloud. Use their APi instead.

see:

https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world

Comment: Yeah I' have spent 8 hours looking at that but its too vague. Is there any other online `Cloud SQL` which can be easily connected to via `php`

Comment: Are you sure you can do that?

Comment: Im new to php. Idk much. The only easy method i know is mysqli_connect